# How to match alpha numeric elements with array javascript

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script

I have an array which I captured it from google spreadsheet.

`arr = [abc@gmail.com, xyz@gmail.com, pqr123@gmail.com.....]`

Every other match is giving 0. however, I have a value which is `pqr123@gmail.com` which is throwing result -1. I realized that it is alpha numeric and that could be the reason to not match. but again if the array element is alphanumeric it should match. what is the solution?

I am using the following code to match :-

```
  var arr = sheet2.getRange(4,1,sheet.getLastRow(),1).getValues();

  var match = arr[0].indexOf(eRecord.email) //eRecord.email is 'pqr123@gmail.com'

  Logger.log(match) //current result -1
```

Comment: This would ALWAYS work: `["abc@gmail.com", "xyz@gmail.com", "pqr123@gmail.com"].indexOf('pqr123@gmail.com')` and would return 2. Something else is going on

Comment: Log `arr[0]` and `eRecord.email` as well and see if the latter actually exists in `arr[0]`.

Comment: From `getRange(4,1,sheet.getLastRow(),1)`, in your case, `var match = arr.flat().indexOf(eRecord.email)` might be able to be used for retrieving the row index.

Comment: ahh you are correct using `.flat()` did the job.

Comment: @Tanaike may I kindly ask you if you can post your answer? so the community can upvote your solution

Comment: @Jeff Rush Thank you for your comment and support. By your comment, I had noticed OP's replying, and I could post it as an answer. Thank you so much.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your script, you use `getRange(4,1,sheet.getLastRow(),1)` of `var arr = sheet2.getRange(4,1,sheet.getLastRow(),1).getValues();` as the range. In this case, the values are retrieved from a column. From this situation, I would like to propose the following modification.

#### From:

```
var match = arr[0].indexOf(eRecord.email)
```

#### To:

```
var match = arr.flat().indexOf(eRecord.email);
```

- By this modification, 2 dimensional array with 1 dimensional array which has one element are flatten, and the returned value is the row index.

#### Reference:

- [flat()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/flat)

Answer (score 0):

I think that the problem could be in **arr[0]** or **eRecord.email**. Please, doublecheck that **arr[0]** is really what you need and **eRecord.email** contains email.